# Ruby on Rails: Return values not blank/empty/false/nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this

```
 hash = {"foo"=>nil,"bar"=>false,"zoo"=>"monkey","loo"=>"","hoo"=>"   "}
```

I want to reject foo, loo, and hoo

what is the appropriate method to do that?

Comment: hash.reject { |k, v| !v.present? && !v.blank?}
is it best way?

Comment: just `hash.reject {|_,v| v.blank?}` or `hash.select {|_,v| v.present? }` since `present?` is `!blank?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

code

```
 p hash.delete_if{|_,v| v.to_s.strip.empty? }
```

Comment: `false.to_s #=> "false"`

Comment: adding a complexity to original question. want to reject empty arrays also. for example:
hash={"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>false, "zoo"=>"monkey", "loo"=>"", "hoo"=>" ", "koo"=>[]}

Comment: If that was the case, then I would have written a different code

Comment: thank you @Rajagopalan